# WPF ListBox in MenuItem. How to keep menu from closing when clicking in ListBox?

Tags: wpf, listbox, contextmenu, menuitem

I'm attempting to create Excel-like sorting/filtering in a DataGrid. I created this ContextMenu with a ListBox inside the Header of a MenuItem.

[image: The ContextMenu]

When I click on a checkbox or the text of the checkbox, it behaves as expected. However, if I click in the whitespace of the checkbox/listbox or in the header space outside of the listbox, the ContextMenu closes.

It's not in the screenshot yet, but i'll be adding OK & Cancel buttons below the listbox. Clicking one of them is when I want the ContextMenu to close.

In case you need the XAML, here it is:

```
    <MenuItem x:Name="miListBox"
              Focusable="False">
        <MenuItem.Header>
                <ListBox MaxHeight="150" Focusable="False">

                </ListBox>
        </MenuItem.Header>
    </MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ContextMenu` has a property called `StaysOpen`. Just set it to `true` to not allow it to auto-close and then you need to use the `IsOpen` property to open/close it manually:

```
<ContextMenu StaysOpen="true">
    <ContextMenu.Resources>

    <!-- ... --->
</ContextMenu>
```

**Edit**:

From MSDN, the `StaysOpen` property should have worked as the name suggests however looks like it's simply ***useless***. Because it does not work expectedly. Somehow the `IsOpen` is always set to false ***automatically*** when one of the MenuItems is clicked or when we click outside the ContextMenu. And as in the documentation about `StaysOpen`, the `ContextMenu` is still closed when `IsOpen` is set to false. The problem here is we don't set that manually but it's automatically set somehow and hence the ***uselessness*** of `StaysOpen`.

We can set the `StaysOpenOnClick` on each MenuItem instead:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
              <Setter Property="StaysOpenOnClick" Value="True"/>
         </Style>
    </ContextMenu.Resources>
    <!-- ... -->
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: I thought you had saved my bacon until I tried it. The ContextMenu still closes when I click on the ListBox (and any other menu item). I read [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.staysopen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and it says 'until an event occurs that changes the IsOpen property to False'.  I see no difference in behavior changing the StaysOpen property to True or False.

Edit: However, your suggestion made me look for a StaysOpen property on the MenuItem itself. I found StaysOpenOnClick and I set it to True for that MenuItem and now it works.

Comment: @tolsen64 do you have any Binding involving `IsOpen` property? Looks like the `IsOpen` is set to false somewhere in your code (including XAML code).

Comment: I edited my first comment to say that I found a StaysOpenOnClick property on the MenuItem. I set that to True and it works like I wanted it to.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.